# Ubuntu login on a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I just got a Raspberry Pi 2 and put Ubuntu on a microSD card with [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/?source=typ_redirect). When starting up I get the following:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
ubuntu login:
```

What should I type in there?

Comment: The [Ubuntu Raspi community](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) has login information.

Comment: Thanks, I looked there but I overread it at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Ubuntus wiki on RaspberryPi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi),

> Login username is "ubuntu", password is "ubuntu"

- on the prompt "ubuntu login:" you should type in **ubuntu** and hit enter.
- Next when it asks for the "password:" again type in **ubuntu** and hit enter.
  *(note that the password is kept invisible on the command line, make sure you are hitting the correct keys)*

Answer (score 1):

Login username is "ubuntu", password is "ubuntu".

Taken from:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi